# What is the default value for an omitted rules in TSLint?

Tags: tslint

I looked through the documentation but couldn't figure out what the default value of a rule in TSLint is. If I don't specify one of the rules found here (https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/) then does it default to false?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Configuring TSLint page](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/usage/configuration/):

> **Rule severity**
>
> The severity level of each rule can be configured to default, error, warning/warn, or off/none. If no severity level is specified, default is used. The defaultSeverity top-level option replaces the severity level for each rule that uses severity level default in the current file. Valid values for defaultSeverity include error, warning/warn, and off/none.

and

> defaultSeverity?: "error" | "warning" | "off": The severity level that is applied to rules in this config file as well as rules in any inherited config files which have their severity set to “default”. **If undefined, “error” is used as the defaultSeverity.**

To answer your question: the default value for an omitted rule is the value of `defaultSeverity` and if `defaultSeverity` is not set the default value is `error`.

Note also that if you have:

```
"extends": "tslint:recommended"
```

in your tslint.json, you inherit all values set in [recommended.js](https://github.com/palantir/tslint/blob/master/src/configs/recommended.ts).